# Check Permission on Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm writing a plugin on redmine. I took project and user permissions to my plugin to access a button in a page of redmine.

**What i want:**

Display a button only when the user AND the project have permissions to do it.

Below my code:

**_navigation.html.erb**

```
<% if ?????? -%> Here is the codition where display or not the button.
    <div style="float: left; width: auto; padding-right: 1%">  
    <%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'printar', :controller => 'GerarVersao')%>
    </div>
<% end -%>
```

**init.rb**

```
  permission :view_repository, :gerar_versao_projeto => :exec_client

  project_module :gerar_versao_projeto do
     permission :view_repository, :gerar_versao_projeto => :exec_client
  end
```

**gerar_versao_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :find_project, :authorize, :only => :exec_client

def exec_client
.
.
.
end

private

def find_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

So anyone knows what I have to put in my if, to display the button only when the User or Project have permission to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by my myself. The answer is simple. I just followed the proverb "In the life nothing is created everything is copied" :) and copied a existing code from the redmine as listed below:

```
<% if User.current.allowed_to?(:view_repository, @project) -%>
```

With this "if" I check if the user is allowed to view my button inside the project. Is important to note that the :view_repository is the permission which i have put.

Questions about the solution, please feel free to discuss.

Best regards and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom method in model to judge if the user is permitted

```
# model
def permittable?
  he_is_in_some_types_say_exec_client ? true :false
end
```

Then in view, call this method on current user.

```
# view
<% if current_user.permittable? %>
   <%= show_something %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Err, this answer was not clear to me. Add the method into what model? How do I check if the user is permitted? And with projects? Do the same?

Comment: @user2195342, it is on User model as you can see the method is called on a user instance. For any other criteria, they are similar, just call a method on user to see if it returns true or not.